# Convert astable multivibrator square output waveform to sawtooth

Tags: analog, multivibrator

I designed an astable multivibrator by using BJT (necessary) to produce a square waveform.  How I convert the output signal from a square to a ramp waveform?

Answer (score 2):

[image: astable]

Resistors R6 and R7 act together to tune the rising and falling edges of the triangle.

[image: astfuresz]

Comment: YES, but I want to modify the circuit to produce a sawtooth waveform

Comment: @Ahmad Alhayashi  The sawtooth waveform will be simpler.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

An op-amp integrator will do exactly that.

[Here's an op-amp integator example. (Falstad sim)](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAXKQUgCgBzEYwkFFAFiZcxSloHcQ2bCzBhew0YUh9BYYrzwz5vMbzpyF4ceC1h2nDbtUZRWtodoBDY%20GlCRdmXnBIAtGCRh48EG5g%20COz4kOxgeIR4ZGLBhsg%20tADGtmoOojoyAYEubgjQwUrECMTsxNhReNhgtADyaU4gwcr2mbQAblysHJ36cbzBFFBC0PqeCoQI2AhRGGVQ0Ai0AA7gKC4Wqy5KQ62CzF2c4uvdRkcHthtG%209tn23QATpsgN1p38Vcs2-u9fAD2TEJ1I1IMQXEgsnAyBNCChweAQABLAB2SwArgAXWj-cjYIHBUHaeY%20KEIGFeeHI9EAU3o9ysABtaEA):

If you want to ensure a symmetrical waveform, add a divide-by-2 circuit to your oscillator output.

Related: [BJT astable multivibrator generate triangle wave](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/436174/bjt-astable-multivibrator-generate-triangle-wave)

Comment: It will need to be tuned to match the 1/2 period of the square wave.

Comment: yes but the question asked to use BJT

Comment: Quote: "my question is how I convert the output signal from a square to a triangular waveform." You didn't say you needed to use BJT to do that. If that is your intent, please edit your question with that stipulation.

Answer (score 1):

Like other have pointed out, integrating a square-waveform will produce a triangle-waveform, and differentiating a triangle-waveform will produce a square-waveform. To do this, you can use a capacitor or inductor since they both inherently integrate:

$$i = C \frac{dv}{dt}$$
$$v = L \frac{di}{dt}$$

Apply KCL/KVL to the circuit below and you'll see how a voltage signal can be differentiated or integrated:
[image: 4]

Op-amps are good tools to do this, but they're not the only tool designers should be familiar with. Comparators (unlike most op-amps) are specifically designed to saturate and recover quickly. Operational transconductance amplifiers (OTAs) use differential voltage input, single-ended current output and can convert voltage-to-current without needing resistors, which is very useful for integrated circuit design.

In this example, OTAs are used as both integrator and comparator. The positive phase of the square pulse
(IF)
is used to increase the slew rate of the triangular waveform (V01):
[image: 5]

Check out [the LM13700 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm13700.pdf?ts=1650057599745&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) for other examples.